# Contains filter in SODA2 API call

Tags: socrata

Is there any way to use the contains() filter in a SODA2 API call. Something like this, but I get a response saying the query is too complex -

[http://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/4ijn-s7e5.json?$select=dba_name&$where=contains(dba_name,'Some string')](http://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/4ijn-s7e5.json?%24select=dba_name&%24where=contains%28dba_name,%27Some%20string%27%29)

```
{
  "code" : "query.execution.queryTooComplex",
  "error" : true,
  "message" : "Only simple comparison filters are allowed",
  "data" : {
    "reason" : "validation.complex-filter"
  }
}
```

When you view the dataset [here](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Health-Human-Services/Food-Inspections/4ijn-s7e5) you're able to create different filter view conditions like 'DBA Name contains apple', so I was just wondering if there was a way to do the same thing using the SODA2 API endpoint.

This is for an iOS App also. My current solution is just storing a years worth of data on the device and then doing all the operations I need on my own.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about your questions, but perhaps this will help. If you're familiar with `R`, there is a library for connecting with Socrata from `R`, called `RSocrata` http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSocrata/index.html

Comment: I realized my answer below isn't specific to "socrata". Please update your question if you are looking for answers using a specific software or tool.

Comment: I just updated my question, hopefully it is more specific now.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: I realized my answer is for the browser and not related to Socrata. I'll probably delete it soon.

---

Your core URI is

```
http://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/4ijn-s7e5.json
```

which is actually just a large [JSON file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

It's possible to use the browser to filter the JSON file. After the core [URI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/176274/2327328) above, you put a question mark (?) and then the filters. For example, to get inspection_id # 1434955, the URL will be constructed as follows:

```
http://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/4ijn-s7e5.json?inspection_id=1434955
```

The **key** from the JSON file is *inspection_id* and the **value** is *1434955*. These strings must match exactly, so it's most useful to use the complete JSON as a reference.

You can combine filters with ampersand (&). For example, this URI gives a JSON that combines all Zip Codes being 60649 and with Inspection Type being "Complaint"

```
http://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/4ijn-s7e5.json?zip=60649&inspection_type=Complaint
```

The **keys** are things like *zip* and *inspection_type*, and the **values** are things like *60649* and *Complaint*. There is also the ability to give the browser JSON with more complicated filters (greater than, less than), but those will require some documentation from the data source. Normally you put a JSON-like piece of text in your URI ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19904091/2327328)). If you use a browser tool like [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2368279/2327328), I think then you can easily search text in the JSON file.

If you don't know programming, consider learning [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) (don't mind the tacky website, it's really a core resource). Also, there are browser extensions that may make the process simpler ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9522536/2327328)).

Comment: Actually, what you're describing is the [CGI interface](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875) ... effectively the URL is of the form `protocol://host/path?query`, and the query is composed of `key=value` pairs, joined by ampersands (`&`).  Note that some CGI interfaces will also accept semi-colons in place of ampersands, which is useful as they don't have to be escaped in the HTML.